# Refactor EmberJS View by removing the duplicate jquery code

Tags: ember.js, view, refactoring

I theme of the code is that i have an application where the user enters a search string and on submit, the application redirect to another application(created using emberjs). Here, we have a dropdown created using bootstrap and a search box( $('#query') ). The search box needs to be populated with the search string and the dropdown needs to be set to some option.

The didInsertElement is a callback provided by emberjs and searchStringChanged is an observer that observes the searchString(in the url) and repopulates the searchbox with the updated searchString.

My current controller code is as:

```
App.PortfoliosIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(                                                                               
  queryParams: ['search_string']
  search_string: null

  filteredPortfolios: (->
    search_string = @get("search_string")
    results = @get('content')

    if search_string
      results = results.filter((portfolio) ->
        portfolio.get('portfolio_name').toLowerCase().indexOf(search_string.toLowerCase()) > -1
    )
    results
  ).property('content', 'search_string')
)
```

My current ember view code is as:

```
App.PortfoliosListView = Ember.View.extend(Ember.PaginationMixin,
  templateName: 'portfolios/list'

  itemsPerPage: 5

  modifySelectBox: ->
    $('#query').val @searchString
    $(".dropdown-menu ul li").removeClass "selected"
    $(".dropdown-menu ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass "selected"
    $(".filter-option").text $(".dropdown-menu ul li.selected a span").text()
    $("#category").get(0).selectedIndex = 1

  searchStringChanged: (->
    ###
    $('#query').val @searchString
    $(".dropdown-menu ul li").removeClass "selected"
    $(".dropdown-menu ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass "selected"
    $(".filter-option").text $(".dropdown-menu ul li.selected a span").text()
    $("#category").get(0).selectedIndex = 1
    ###
    modifySelectBox()
  ).observes 'searchString'

  didInsertElement: ->
    ###
    $('#query').val @searchString
    $(".dropdown-menu ul li").removeClass "selected"
    $(".dropdown-menu ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass "selected"
    $(".filter-option").text $(".dropdown-menu ul li.selected a span").text()
    $("#category").get(0).selectedIndex = 1
    ###
    modifySelectBox()
)
```

I removed the duplicate code and moved it to an modifySelectBox method which i intended to call from callback and observer but the modification doesnt work. How can remove the duplication?

Comment: Just put the code in a function and chain the obeserver like .observes('searchString').on('didInsertElement')

Comment: One of your issues may be that `didInsertElement` fires after the **parent element** of the view is rendered in the DOM.  If that view contains other elements, they may not be rendered until after `didInsertElement` is called.  Look at http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/ for details.

Comment: I also see that you're setting the value of the search textbox using jQuery `.val()`.  Using jQuery in this way can sometimes expose you to race conditions.  You might consider using query_params (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/) to populate your search box instead.

Comment: @JoshPadnick i am using query params but its not populating the search box. hence added jquery.

Comment: @blessenm if you post the comment as an answer, i will accept it as the correct one. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain observers and event hooks in ember. Here is how it will look.

```
 modifySelectBox: function() {
   $('#query').val(this.get('searchString');
   $(".dropdown-menu ul li").removeClass('selected');
   $(".dropdown-menu ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass('selected');
   $(".filter-option").text($(".dropdown-menu ul li.selected a span").text());
   $("#category").get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
 ).observes('searchString').on('didInsertElement')
```